# Own code noticeably slower than others

Tags: c#

The code i wrote is slower (Max Time exceeded) than some code i found online, even if the online code looks more bloated.

So what trap did i step into that my code looks cleaner but is slowed down somehow?

Slow (mine):

```
using System;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        int countMAX = 0;
        int num = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {
            int count = 1;

            int temp = i;

            while (temp != 1)
            {
                if(temp % 2 == 0) temp /= 2;
                else temp = temp * 3 + 1;
                count++;
            }

            if(count > countMAX)
            {
                countMAX = count;
                num = i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Number: " + num + " Hops: " +countMAX);
    }
}
```

Fast (online):

```
using System;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int number = 1000000;

        long sequenceLength = 0;
        long startingNumber = 0;
        long sequence;

        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) 
        {
            int length = 1;
            sequence = i;
            while (sequence != 1) 
            {
                if ((sequence % 2) == 0) 
                {
                    sequence = sequence / 2;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    sequence = sequence * 3 + 1;
                }

                length++;
            }

        //Check if sequence is the best solution
            if (length > sequenceLength) 
            {
                sequenceLength = length;
                startingNumber = i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Num: " + startingNumber + " Count: " + sequenceLength);
    }
}
```

I tested it on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), where [my solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WBYV95) get the following error

> Fatal Error: Execution time limit was exceeded

and the [other solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/igRVdr) print the correct result

> Num: 837799 Count: 525

They should be doing the same thing 1:1. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Looks more like a question for Code Review. You can start by naming the variables equally so the code is easier to compare.

Comment: How did you test the performance of both?

Comment: Anyway both code blocks indeed appear to do the same, so if the input is the same, there's no reason for either to take significantly more time than the other.

Comment: your "number" is 10^6 and their "number" is 10^5

Comment: Yes sorry about 100'000 < 1'000'000 thats because i was testing. They both run 1'000'000 normally. I tested it via https://dotnetfiddle.net/ Online-Compiler. Mine exceeds time to run and the other runs in 2.5 secs or something

Comment: You should add how you tested it and how we can reproduce it to your question. :) Without having looked at the code, I can confirm I get the same error with your code.

Comment: The only difference now then would be that the bottom one doesn't redeclare the `sequence` variable, (and variable type)

Comment: @Sayse I can´t see how this should make any difference as `sequence` is set to `i` in both cases.

Comment: ...and using `/=` instead of `x = x / 2`, and using `< const` instead of `< 1000000`. But it seems out of those the deal breaker is indeed declaring the sequence variable. @HimBromBeere I am not an expert but the compiler might allocate space for that int at every iteration.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I don't think it would make it a major difference at all, but its the only difference I can see and it means that in the online code, the variable doesn't go out of scope

Comment: @MAV You can paste both codes to https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and will see that one compiles and mine doesnt. *in time

Comment: @Unfrieden I know. I tried it. I just think it is better to have that information in the question, rather than in the comments. :) I edited you question to add the information

Comment: AHHH but of course.... `temp % 2 == 0` does not equal `(temp % 2) == 0`!!!

Comment: @MAV i wrote it originally but someone cut it out :(

Comment: @YanirKleiman I thought that briefly, but I don't think that is the problem

Comment: One important difference is on the datatypes, in your code you use `int` where in the onlie-version they chosed `long`. I tested it and your program is within endless loop for `i = 113383`. Obviously `temp` has data-overflow when declared as int and thus can get unpredictable values when multiplying with 3. Using `long` for `temp` fixes your code.

Comment: @HimBromBeere coughs quietly and points at the answer below...

Comment: Thanks alot everyone, so in the progress of     else temp = temp * 3 + 1; it just got too high for int i assume

Comment: @Unfrieden Exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing that makes the difference seems to be `int` vs `long`. I wonder if the slow code using `int` is suffering an overflow bug that is making it loop far far longer, and using `long` makes it not overflow. Specifically, `long sequence` (fast  version) vs `int temp = i;` (slow version). If you use `long temp = i;` it works like the fast code.

Sure enough, if we wrap the code in a `checked` block, it throws an `OverflowException` on the line `else temp = temp * 3 + 1;`

Comment: You are right!! So why use int at all? I mean in general for other projects too.

Comment: 1: because in most cases, `int` is more than sufficient; 2: because it is faster and smaller (which can matter if you are dealing in high volume); 3: because it is guaranteed to be atomic (not torn) on x86 (for folks who still need 32-bit), 4: for binary compatibility with systems that use 32-bit integers